# Is there a way to make certain strings or values equivalent to other strings or values in JS?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Can you make a string or value like the word "Pinapple" be equivalent to the number 5 so that in if statements `if("Pineapple" == 5)` be true? I am trying to learn Japanese and am using Google Sheets script editor and if there was a way to make "海洋" = "Ocean" or "A" = "あ" would be really useful to me. Specifically what I'm trying to do is to be able to assign words values so I could simplify the current convoluted code that I have currently:

```
function Check(Cell,check) {
  if(Cell=='あ' && check.toUpperCase()!='A'){
    return "X"}
  else if(Cell=='あ' && check.toUpperCase()=='A'){
    return "✓"}
  else if(Cell=='い' && check.toUpperCase()!='I'){
    return "X"}
  else if(Cell=='い' && check.toUpperCase()=='I'){
    return "✓"}
  else if(Cell=='う' && check.toUpperCase()!='U'){
    return "X"}
  else if(Cell=='う' && check.toUpperCase()=='U'){
    return "✓"}
  else if(Cell=='え' && check.toUpperCase()!='E'){
    return "X"}
  else if(Cell=='え' && check.toUpperCase()=='E'){
    return "✓"}
  else if(Cell=='お' && check.toUpperCase()!='O'){
    return "X"}
  else if(Cell=='お' && check.toUpperCase()=='O'){
    return "✓"}
}
```

and

```
function RandomVowel(max) {
  var array = ["あ","い","う","え","お"];
  var RandomValue = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  return RandomValue
}
```

The more characters I add, the more convoluted it gets so I want an easier way of doing this and if there is a way to assign words values this would be much easier. Apart from assigning strings with values specifically, an easier method for what I am trying to accomplish with any method would also be accepted and appreciated.

EDIT: Just to clarify more, I want to make things universally equal instead of having to call a specific value from an array to make it equal. I want it so that if I compare two different cells when one of them is "A" and the other one is "あ" the comparison would be true. For example, if Cell is A1, and check is A2 where A1 is 'A' and A2 is 'あ', the comparison `if(Cell==A2){return "They are the same"}` would return "They are the same" since the two values would be globally equal. I am not trying to specifically compare values that I defined or are in the same array, but I also want to compare cell values that are not formatted in the way that could satisfy a comparison like `array['え']=='E'` since the value in the Google Sheet cells is not `array['value']` but just normal text.

Comment: So you have only a fixed set of words?

Comment: Sounds like a map might help? Something like `myMap['え'] = 'E'` and/or `otherMap['E'] = 'え'`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that.

Comment: It doesn't accomplish what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to set the following strings as equivalent:

1. `"5" == "Pineapple"`
2. `"海洋" == "Ocean"`
3. `"あ" == "A"`

I would then use a javascript object, called `myDictionary`, to set this up:

```js
var myDictionary = {
  "5": "Pineapple",
  "海洋": "Ocean",
  "あ": "A"
}
```

And then, instead of writing `if("5" == "Pineapple")` or `if("海洋" == "Ocean")`, write:

```js
if (myDictionary["5"] == "Pineapple") {
  ...
}

if (myDictionary["海洋"] == "Ocean") {
  ...
}
```

Comment: It works on your case, but I'm looking for something that could make things universally equal so that even "5"=="Pineapple" would be true.

Comment: Maybe you could define a 3rd group of symbols that your two other groups map to. So, `myMap['5'] == "1"` and `otherMap["Pineapple"] == "1"` and therefore `myMap["5"] == otherMap["Pineapple"]`.

Comment: That may work like the answer provided by @Run_Script, but again doesn't globally affect the two values' status so that `5==Pineapple` would be true

Comment: If you are looking for a way to evaluate the exact statement `5==Pineapple` as true, I'm not sure there is a way to do that in js unless Pineapple is the name of a variable. But there is probably a similar way with either maps or spreadsheet lookups.

Comment: I see... Then is there a way that is Google Spreadsheets specific?